# git push heroku master issue

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, git, heroku

I am having a problem with my application not being uploaded to heroku. When I typed in: 
git push heroku master

I get an error at the end:

****Results logged to /tmp/build_2akv91a7tpdfl/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sqlite3-1.3.7/ext/sqlite3/gem_make.out
       An error occurred while installing sqlite3 (1.3.7), and Bundler cannot continue.
       Make sure that `gem install sqlite3 -v '1.3.7'` succeeds before bundling.
 !
 !     Failed to install gems via Bundler.
 !
 !     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby/Rails app****

When i tried installing the gems its asking for, and redid the process the same error message comes up even after i installed 'gem install sqlite3 -v '1.3.7.''

(For those who are following Michael Hartl rails tutorials i followed it by detail but I'm still getting an error message.)

Any help will be greatly appreciated. I am new to rails so if you have a solution, please do speak in layman's terms.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can use sqlite3 on Heroku. You can use postgres instead.

Remove sqlite3 gem and add pg gem in your Gemfile.

```
gem 'pg'
```

Comment: I tried what you said but it still did not work, I am still getting the same error message. Would you happen to know any other solutions? If heroku doesnt use sqlite3, why is my IDE asking for it in order for the push to work?

Answer (score 0):

Since Heroku provides you a PostgreSQL database for your app, edit your Gemfile and change this line:

gem 'sqlite3'
To this:

gem 'pg'